# Select visible text from combo box

Tags: karate

I need to select an item from drop box. I tried below steps

1. I clicked on the combo box and the list opened
2. Used below line to select the visible item from the list. But item not selected and the script passed

   - And select("//div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div']", '{}Delhi')

**Note:**
I am getting result like below below for command-  **script("/**/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div**']", "function(e){ return e.innerHTML }")**

```
<div class=" css-1n7v3ny-option" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1">Kerala</div>
<div class=" css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-1" tabindex="-1">Delhi</div>
<div class=" css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-2" tabindex="-1">Tamilnadu</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
* click('{}Delhi')
```

That should be more than enough. Please try to read the docs and understand when to use `select()` it is only for select boxes but here it is normal HTML.